# How to monitor the data in both source and destination folders?

Tags: c, inotify

I'm working on the file monitoring system project in which, first all the data will be copied to the destination folder then it should monitor the data in both source and destination folders. But unfortunately, it is just monitoring the data from the **source folder**.

I divided the **inotify function** into two parts because I used `inotifyFunc1` to help me in copying the folders first. And once the data is copied then I used `inotifyFunc2` to monitor the data in **both folders**. But as I said it is just monitoring the first **source folder.**

*This code is big but I don't know how to make it understand in a short way.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STRING_LEN 200
#define MAX_EVENTS 1024
#define NAME_LEN 16
#define EVENT_SIZE (sizeof(struct inotify_event))
#define BUFFER_LEN (MAX_EVENTS * (EVENT_SIZE + NAME_LEN))

typedef struct{
    int fd, wd, result, length;
    uint32_t mask[2];
    char path1[STRING_LEN], path2[STRING_LEN], cmd[STRING_LEN], option, buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
} monitoring;

monitoring monitor;

void sig_handler(int signal){
    printf("\nThe program is closed\n");
    inotify_rm_watch(monitor.fd, monitor.wd);
    close(monitor.fd);
    exit(0);
}

void inotifyFunc1(char *path1, uint32_t *maskPtr1){
    monitor.fd = inotify_init();
    if(fcntl(monitor.fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)){
       perror("inotify not initialized: ");
       exit(0);
    }

    monitor.wd = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path1, *maskPtr1);
    if(monitor.wd < 0){
        perror("Sorry");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void inotifyFunc2(char *path2, uint32_t *maskPtr2)
{
    while(1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        monitor.length = read(monitor.fd, monitor.buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
        while(i<monitor.length){
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&monitor.buffer[i];
            if(event->len){
                if(event->mask & *maskPtr2){
                    if(event->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                        printf("Directory is created\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("File is created\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void monitoringSystem(char *pathname1, char *pathname2)
{
    /* Closing inotify */
    signal(SIGINT,sig_handler);
    do
    {
        printf("Choose the source path: ");
        scanf("%s", pathname1);

        monitor.mask[0] = ENOENT;
        inotifyFunc1(pathname1, &monitor.mask[0]);

        printf("Choose the destination path: ");
        scanf("%s", pathname2);
        inotifyFunc1(pathname2, &monitor.mask[0]);
        
        monitor.result = strcmp(pathname1, pathname2);
        if(monitor.result == 0){
            printf("Error: Both locations are the same\n");
            exit(3);
        }
        else{
            sprintf(monitor.cmd, "cp -r %s %s", pathname1, pathname2);
            system(monitor.cmd);
            printf("Data is copied from source to destination\n");
        }

        printf("\nBoth locations are being monitored\n");
        monitor.mask[1] = IN_CREATE;
        inotifyFunc1(pathname1, &monitor.mask[1]);
        inotifyFunc2(pathname1, &monitor.mask[1]);

        inotifyFunc1(pathname2, &monitor.mask[1]);
        inotifyFunc2(pathname2, &monitor.mask[1]);
    
        printf("Do you want to give location again? [y/n]: ");
        scanf("%s", &monitor.option);
    } while(monitor.option == 'y');
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("DATA RECOVERY SYSTEM\n");
    printf("WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU\n\n");

    monitoringSystem(monitor.path1, monitor.path2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you are testing this? Do you want until it outputs "Both locations are being monitored" and then do something? If not, what's your procedure? If so, what are you doing after you see that message, what are you expecting to happen, and what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void inotifyFunc1(char *path1, uint32_t *maskPtr1){
        monitor.fd = inotify_init();
```

Your `inotifyFunc1` function creates a brand new `inotify` instance and stores its handle in `monitor.fd`.

```
        inotifyFunc1(pathname1, &monitor.mask[0]);

        printf("Choose the destination path: ");
        scanf("%s", pathname2);
        inotifyFunc1(pathname2, &monitor.mask[0]);
```

But you call it twice. The second time, it again creates a new `inotify` instance and stores its handle in `monitor.fd`, leaking the old handle.

If you only want one `inotify` instance to watch more than one thing, you need to create only one `inotify` instance.

```
        inotifyFunc1(pathname1, &monitor.mask[1]);
        inotifyFunc2(pathname1, &monitor.mask[1]);
```

This also doesn't make sense. Why are you calling `inotifyFunc1` again? If you thought it was already monitoring both locations, what do you think this accomplishes? If you didn't think it was already monitoring both locations, why is this after you say it is?

It's hard to explain what incorrect reasoning led you to call those functions because there are no comments in the code. But it makes no sense.

You want to:

1. Create only one `inotify` instance.
2. Add each location to it only once.

Comment: Will I have to create an `inotify` instance for each destination? And I used `monitor.mask[0]` for `EOENT` and `monitor.mask[1]` for IN_CREATE.

Comment: After `Both locations are monitored`, I want it to show me the message every time I create a new directory or a new file

Comment: I thought that instead of writing inotify every time why should I not use it in a function and call everytime when necessary.

Comment: @InotifyLine See the end of my answer. If you want to monitor two things at once, you need one `inotify` instance that monitors both locations. Your code can't possibly do that because it keeps creating new `inotify` instances.

Comment: How can I write one inotify instance for two locations?  There are two different paths and if I make an instance for the first one, how will it monitor the second location. David, will you please write a code example of it.

Comment: @InotifyLine Just call `inotify_init` only once. Then call `inotify_add_watch` twice.

Comment: Okay bro, thank you! I was not aware of it.